# How to host docker-compose Application on MS Azure?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I want to deploy a containerized Web-App to MS Azure. Therefore I've written the following docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
    frontend:
        image: fitnessappcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/crushit:frontend
        build:
            context: ./frontend
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        networks:
            - crushit
        ports:
            - "80:3000"
        restart: unless-stopped

    wikihow:
        image: fitnessappcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/crushit:backend-wikihow
        build:
            context: ./backend
            dockerfile: ./services/WikiHow Service/Dockerfile
        networks:
            - crushit
        restart: unless-stopped

    training:
        image: fitnessappcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/crushit:backend-training
        build:
            context: ./backend
            dockerfile: ./services/Training Service/Dockerfile
        networks:
            - crushit
        restart: unless-stopped

    eventpublisher:
        image: fitnessappcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/crushit:backend-eventpublisher
        build:
            context: ./backend
            dockerfile: ./services/EventPublisher/Dockerfile
        networks:
            - crushit
        restart: unless-stopped

    accountservice:
        image: fitnessappcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/crushit:backend-account
        build:
            context: ./backend
            dockerfile: ./services/Account Service/Dockerfile
        networks:
            - crushit
        restart: unless-stopped
    proxy:
        image: fitnessappcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/crushit:backend-proxy
        build:
            context: ./backend
            dockerfile: ./proxy/Dockerfile
        networks:
            - crushit
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        restart: unless-stopped
networks:
    crushit:
        driver: bridge
```

For the App to function, two Containers (frontend, proxy) have to be exposed to the outside. Additionally all Containers have to be able to communicate with each other (therefore I added a custom network to all services). All Container-Images are stored in an Azure Container Registry.
Now I'm wondering how I can host my App on Azure. I already tried "Web App for Containers" which is the same as "App Services" I think. That didn't work fully, as I was not able to expose a "non standard" Port like 5000.
Is there any other way to host my App on Azure using this docker-compose file, or do I have to use Kubernetes instead?

Comment: In time of writing Azure Kubernetes Service is only multi-container service in Azure. You can deploy multiple containers in Azure App Service but it is currently in preview https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the docker-compose.yml file to deploy containers in the Azure Web App for container. And there is something you need to know.

First, the Azure Web App only can expose one port to the outside. So it means you can only expose one container to the outside, not two.

Second, if you expose a port other than 80 or 443, then you can use the environment variable `WEBSITES_PORT` to let Azure know. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#your-container-must-respond-to-an-http-pingapplies-to-web-app-for-containers) is the documentation.

Third, the Web App only supports a part of the options of the docker-compose, here you can see the supported options and the unsupported options.

The last one is that all the containers in the Web App can communicate with each other via the port that the container exposes. So you don't need to set the `network` option.